# Don't know how to make an SKOverlayScene in SceneKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I have been trying for a while to make a sprite kit to make buttons for my app however all of the solutions are outdated or just don't work. This is the best solution I could find, but it is outdated and it just won't work. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/combining-the-power-of-spritekit-and-scenekit--cms-24049

I tried to convert it to new swift syntax but i run into an error that I am not sure how to fix. Can someone please help

Comment: Create a new SpriteKit Project, make your overlay in the SKS builder, save it as overlay.sks, and transfer it over to your scene kit project

Comment: I know where to put it but I don't know the syntax to make the SKOverlayScene

Comment: Did you import sprite kit into your scene class?

Comment: Then it is `self.overlaySKScene = SKScene(...`